# Why do some telegram channels use names and others not?

Tags: telegram

Usually, telegram channels use specific names for shortcut links, e.g.:

- https://t.me/lifeyt

However, sometimes I see channels without a specific name but with the join link:

- https://t.me/joinchat/AAAAAEG9D2xsO4xhFP_EFQ

Any idea why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of channel types. Public channels have a link which can be set manually. A private channel has a randomly generated link. It can be revoked/reset any time.

[image]